# Need Help With H1 Tags for Product Sub-pages

Tags: seo, tags

The site I'm currently building will feature a range of products for the organization it represents. Each product will have a main landing page and a series of sub-pages for "About", "Pricing", "Contact", etc.

I'm a bit confused on the best way to handle the `h1` tags for these pages. Each page will have the organization's logo as an image at the top. For the landing page of each product I was planning on `<h1>Product Name</h1>`However, on the sub-pages, I'd still like to retain the title of the product.... Would it be acceptable to use `<h1>Product Name — About</h1>`, `<h1>Product Name – Pricing</h1>`? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: And by better way, you mean?

Comment: @BackinaFlash A better way to format the h1 tags—besides the example I gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really aren't any better ways... **1 h1 tag/page** that's all you need to keep in mind. Also maintaining a structure/page would be good

```
<h1> - main title
  <h2> - section
    <p> - some intro text
    <h3> - section chapter
     <p> - chapter contents
  <h2> - section
    <h3> - chapter
     <p> - chapter contents
    <h3> - chapter
     <p> -chapter contents
```

Even if the pages are related, it doesn't matter how many h1 tags you use... just create an easy to follow hierarchy on each individual page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice in a situation like this is to use the h1 for your product name and then a different heading tag for the other content.  Logically, it would be h2.